# "Хам" — этимология слова

Tags: этимология, семантика, история, историческая-грамматика, историческое-словообразование

Действительно ли обзывательство "хам" имеет библейское происхождение?

Comment: Есть собственная версия? Сообщите, ведь это так актуально.

Comment: Зачем версии, когда есть словари? Почему Вы ими не пользуетесь? По-моему, легче, по крайней мере быстрее набрать в поисковике, чем ждать, когда кто-то наберёт и Вам ответит. Тем более, что ни один ответ так и не принят. https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D1%85/%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BC

Comment: @Людмила выкладки голословны.

Comment: @Людмила В старославянской библии наберется с десяток семитских имён, которые прекрасно ложатся на русские глаголы.

Comment: @Людмила Садок (первосвященник)